# how to have custom-icon for date input field

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, mobile

I'm trying to have custom icon for a date input field as in this [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7edAG.png). Though I've created custom-icon on button, I couldn't create one for date field.

```
<div id="send-date" class="transaction-details" data-role="fieldcontain" data-theme="gr">
   <label for="date">Send on</label>
   <input type="date" name="date" id="date" value="" placeholder="" data-icon="date" data-iconpos="right" />
</div><!-- /send-date -->
```

IS THERE ANYOTHER WAY TO DO THIS?

[link to code](http://jsfiddle.net/Wab8w/)
[link to custom-icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdH1b.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have build an example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/WFz37/

You need to wrap input with same div used to wrap input filed used for listview filtering. After that apply this java script:

```
$('input[type="text"]').removeClass('ui-input-text ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset').addClass('ui-input-text');
$('#custom-input-wrapper').removeClass('ui-icon-searchfield').addClass('ui-custom-icon');
```

Only requirement are 16x16 images but I think you can use even bigger one, in that case play with a css to create needed style.

Comment: since the site I'm working on is mainly for iOS, using a background img on <input> seems to work. When the page is viewed on the iOS device, arrow is not displayed. http://haripriyaa.zymichost.com/ot/purchase_01.html

Comment: how to change the placeholder text on date field? if see the img, placeholder text reads Today (11/29/2012). But on my page, it reads Month/day/year. HOW to change it?

Comment: First sorry I wasn't looking you were asking for date picker. Can I give you and advice use mobipicker datepicker, if you want I will create you an example how to use it. If you still want to use this component then use this line: $('input[type="date"]').val('Today (' + $('input[type="date"]').val() + ')'); Show it only on current day. If you want better time format use: http://momentjs.com/ to format date.

Comment: I still have few clarifications, will u be able to join chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/20338/jquery-mobile?tab=general

Comment: I'm trying to have custom icon for a date input field as in this img haripriyaa.zymichost.com/ot/…
with bg gradient. since I added the bg-img, i couldn't do bg-gradient. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Don't have time for chat now but tell me for what platform are you creating this app? It it is css3 compatible it can use multiple backgrounds: http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/, so nothing can prevent you to use backg. img with backg. gradient.

Comment: If you want, send me an email and tell me in details what kind of date picker you want (affects and etc.) and I will find it/create it you.

Comment: can u send me email-id pls? thnx

Comment: Its css3. jsfiddle.net/Wab8w/9
i'm not sure whether its related to date picker..I want to customize the placeholder text on "date" input field
It is CSS3 compatible but for some reason I couldn't make it work